Wait until ScrollBar disappeared or Pages/Views fully loaded
I have a .NET MAUI App and test the Android part via Appium and UiAutomator2. I take Screenshots and compare them to a reference file.
In general, this is working fine. But, sometimes these tests fail since the Android Emulator is still showing a ScrollBar from a ScrollView of a View I was navigating to.
Is there a way, I can detect that the ScrollBar in the ScrollView is not displayed anymore? I tried finding the ScrollBar as an Element via Appium Inspector, but there is not scrollbar element.
Is there a good way how I can determine the time I have to wait until I can take my Screenshot and not waiting too long?
I know that sometimes tests wait for certain elements until they are present. But, I don't know what I should even wait for to determine that my View was loaded completely. And when I watch the UI Automation while the tests are executed, it appears that everything was loaded completely, but the ScrollBar is still visible for a certain time and then disappears.
Do you have any ideas how I can determine the time I have to wait until the Views I am displaying are fully loaded?
